# Joining different items in an array at odd intervals using python, regex and join()

Tags: python, arrays, regex, sorting

I am building a program in Python that takes data from a website and stores it into a database. My question is around formatting data that I collect from the websites. Once I scrape them I put them into an array to format. I ran into a problem with the ingredients data, mainly the measurement used and then the amount for the measurement. My array would have a range of amounts, measurements and sometimes just whole amounts but all separate.

**Example:**

```
amount = ['1', 'Teaspoon', '2', '0.75', 'Cups', '0.5', 'Tablespoons', '5']
```

As you can see 'Teaspoon', 'Cups', 'Tablespoons' are separate from their corresponding amount, which is the number that come before them. The solo numbers, '2' and '5' represent whole amounts (like 2 eggs or 5 oranges) so I don't really need to worry about them.

**I needed the data like so:**

```
amount = ['1 Teaspoon', '2', '0.75 Cups', '0.5 Tablespoons', '5']
```

I have made some code that does just that however I feel like there must be a better way of completing this task

**Code:**

```
    amount = ['1', 'Teaspoon', '2', '0.75', 'Cups', '0.5', 'Tablespoons', '5']
    minus1 = 0
    plus1 = 0
    count = 0
    for i in amount :

       if minus1 >= 1 :
           minus1 = count
           minus1 -=1
       if plus1 >= 1 :
           plus1 = count
           plus1 +=1

       strCheck = re.search(r"[a-z]", i)
       if strCheck != None :
           amount[minus1:plus1] = [' '.join(amount[minus1:plus1])]

       minus1 +=1
       plus1 +=1
       count +=1

   print(amount)
```

I am looking for an alternative to what I have made, is there anyway to achieve the same results but without the use of the int counters? Is the join() Method really the only option here? For identifying strings or alphabet characters inside the array is Regex the best option?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add an explanation of the code > It goes through each item in the array > checks to see it it contains any alphabet characters > if it does them It merges it with the array element that precedes it > continues until no items are left > prints out the formatted array

Comment: Rather than try and fix the *output* of your scraping code, why not fix the scraping code so it gives you the correct output to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just join it all

```
s = ' '.join(words)
```

then use re.split

```
solution = re.split("(\d+\.?\d* [a-zA-Z]+)",s)
```

this gets you quite close you probably need to strip out some excess whitespace and remove empty entries, but this gets you most of the way there

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to **Joran Beasley** for [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59607845/11612468)

```
amount = ['1', 'Teaspoon', '2', '0.75', 'Cups', '0.5', 'Tablespoons', '5']

sol = list(filter(None, re.split("\s?(\d+\.?\d*\s*[a-zA-Z]+)\s?", ' '.join(amount))))
print(sol)
```

Here,
1. `re.split` is used for splitting given string by regex expression.
2. given string to `split` function is `' '.join(amount)`
3. `join(amount)` makes a string from list separated by a space.
4. `filter` built-in function is used to filter-out empty/invalid entries.
5. outer most - `list` function packs result of `filter` into list container.